# why scala compiler failed to infer type when i write PairDStreamFunctions.reduceByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wonder why scala compiler couldn't infer a type of my function parameter when i using PairDStreamFunctions.reduceByKey,here is code:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
ssc.checkpoint(".checkpoint")
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words
  .map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, 4)  //here i must specify the type Int,and this format can't work : reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y, 4)
```

here **i must specify the type Int** of my function parameter like **reduceByKey((x: Int, y: Int) => x + y, 4)** when i use **PairDStreamFunctions**.reduceByKey ,and this format **couldn't work** : **reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y, 4)**.

On the other hand,when i use PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey api,it can infer the type,here is the code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(
  "hi what"
  , "show you"
  , "matter how"
))
rdd.flatMap(_.split(" "))
  .map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y, 4)//in this code,scala compiler could infer the type of my function parameter (x,y) => x+y
```

When i use  **PairRDDFunctions**.reduceByKey, **reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y, 4) could work.**
I really don't understand what makes it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the `PairRDDFunctions` method only has one overload of def
`reduceByKey(func: (V, V) ⇒ V, [SOMETHING])` whereas `PairDStreamFunctions` has two:

```
def reduceByKey(reduceFunc: (V, V) ⇒ V, numPartitions: Int)
def reduceByKey(reduceFunc: (V, V) ⇒ V, partitioner: Partitioner)
```

So, although the `partitioner` variant should be thrown out as a possibility, it still comes in and confuses the compiler. You can see this by explicitly naming it:

```
.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y,partitioner = 4)
```

I'm not sure where this falls in the compiler definitions, but it is clearly exhibited as the reason per the above.

Comment: It makes sense.But i didn't succeed after trying.I write as:
 
        .reduceByKey(reduceFunc = (x, y) => x + y, numPartitions = 4)

and compiler prompt me to say type mismatch,expected:(Int,Int)=>Int,Actual:[Nothing,Nothing]=>Any

Comment: .reduceByKey(reduceFunc = (x:Int, y:Int) => x + y, numPartitions = 4)
This one works.

Comment: A smidge late on the response, but the above works for me. It compiles without needing the types when you specify the parameters explicitly...

Comment: Never mind...I found that it's a version issue.I found this issue in scala 2.11,and it's solved in scala 2.12.Thank you for your help.